# Add some space befor TOC title in latex

Tags: latex

I trying add some space before TOC , I used `\vspace` but it doesn't work

```latex
\documentclass[12pt, french,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}
   %...
  \vspace*{.3\paperheight} %doesn't work
  \tableofcontents
   %...
  \chapter{chapitre}
  \section{section}
  \subsection{subsection}

  \newpage
  \chapter{chapitre}
  \section{section}
  \subsection{subsection}
\end{document}
```

somebody have solution ?

[image: my problem in pictures]

Comment: Please make a [mre].

Comment: This is bluntly off topic here, I guess. Flagget for moving on LaTeX.

Comment: ok sorry , how to move ,this topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The toc will automatically start a new chapter on a new page. If you use `\vspace` before it, this will still be on the previous page and not have any effect on your toc. However, you can change the definition of the toc and add some space there:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt, french,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\tableofcontents{%
    \if@twocolumn
      \@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
    \else
      \@restonecolfalse
    \fi
    \chapter*{\vspace{5cm}\contentsname
        \@mkboth{%
           \MakeUppercase\contentsname}{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}}%
    \@starttoc{toc}%
    \if@restonecol\twocolumn\fi
    }
\makeatother



\begin{document}
   %...
  \tableofcontents
   %...
  \chapter{chapitre}
  \section{section}
  \subsection{subsection}

  \newpage
  \chapter{chapitre}
  \section{section}
  \subsection{subsection}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the trick of the redefinition, it works perfectly, I started latex recently. I will document myself, to know, how to redefine the commands, for later